# Define \myfun which gives \myfun{a \\ b} = a and \myfun{a} = a

Tags: macros

How can I define a function `\myfun` which gives

`\myfun{a} -> a`

`\myfun{a \\ b} -> a`

`\myfun{a \\ b \\ c} -> a`

`\myfun{$\theta$ \\ b \\ c} -> $\theta$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `expl3`.

Not fully expandable:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfun}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

For a fully expandable macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myfun}{m}
 {
  \test_myfun:w #1 \\ \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \test_myfun:w #1 \\ #2 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

.\myfun{a}. should be .a.

.\myfun{a \\ b}. should be .a.

\myfun{a \\ b \\ c} should be a

\myfun{$\theta$ \\ b \\ c} should be $\theta$

\edef\test{.\myfun{\textbf{a} \\ b \\ c}.}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The periods are used to show that spaces are trimmed. Also `\textbf` in the `\edef` shows that there is no problem with it (because `\tl_trim_spaces:n` behaves…).

The idea is to pass the argument to the function `\test_myfun:w` that has two *delimited* arguments; the first one ends at `\\`, the second one ends at `\q_stop`. Is this safe? Quite, because `\q_stop` is a “quark”, so it's defined to expand to itself, so it's unusable in other contexts. It's therefore very unlikely that it finds its way in the argument to `\myfun`.

The `:w` part in the name means that the function has “weird” arguments.

So in the cases of `a`, `a \\ b` and `a \\ b \\ c` the calls will be

```
\test_myfun:w a\\\qstop
\test_myfun:w a \\ b \\ q_stop
\test_myfun:w a \\ b \\ c \\ q_stop
```

(spaces here are significant, but they aren't in the definition of the function). Thus `#1` is `a` in the first case and `a<space>` in the other two. But this is where `\tl_trim_spaces:n` enters the scene, because its action is to (expandably) remove spaces at either end of its argument *and* of returning the result in a no longer expandable version of itself.

Let's see a possible application. You want to save the author name from user's input such as

```
\author{A. Uthor \\ Department of Tetrapilectomy \\ University of Somewhere}
```

in an internal container, let's say `\author@name`, for your thesis class. In this case expandability is not needed and you just need the first solution; I also add `\author@affil` for the second part.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{m}
 {
  % split the input at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % detach the first item in the sequence
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % now define name and address
  \tl_set_eq:cN { author@name } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:cx { author@affil } { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The first instruction in the final block makes `\author@name` the same as `\l_tmpa_tl`; the second one reinserts `\\` between the remaining items.

Comment: Amazing! I should start learning `expl3`

Answer (score 7):

You can create `\myfun` macro as an expandable macro:

```
\def\myfun #1{\myfunA #1\\\end}
\def\myfunA #1\\#2\end{\stripspace #1\end/ \end/\next{#1}}
\def\stripspace #1 \end/#2\next#3{\ifx\end#2\end #3\else #1\fi}

% test:
\message{"\myfun{a \\ b \\ c}"} % ... prints "a"
\message{"\myfun{a}"}           % ... prints "a"
```

Suppose `\myfun{a // b}`. Then `\myfunA a // b\end` is called and it scans `a`  to its `#1` and  `b` to its `#2`. If you accept the result `a`  (i.e. `a` plus space), then you can simply define

```
\def\myfunA #1\\#2\end{#1}
```

and it is all. But if you want to remove the optional last space from the result, you must define macro `\stripspace` and use it.

Advance of my solution: it is based only on TeX primitive `\def`. You need not any expl3. And it is much better to understand how `\def` works than to learn an extra new language.

Comment: `\myfun{a}` doesn't work. And of course this doesn't survive `\edef` if something like `\textbf` is used. So it's not portable to LaTeX, even if you fix the first case.

Comment: yes... it's not working as intended. But thanks anyway! I like that trick

Comment: The name `\myfun` indicates that the focus is on the result of typesetting in math-mode not on obtaining a specific set of tokens for further processing. Thus the following remark definitely is nitpicking, but `\myfun{{{abc} }\\}` after five expansion steps yields `abc\fi` while one might expect `{{abc} }` or `{abc} `, i.e., something with not more than one level of surrounding curly braces removed. Whether this is relevant depends on info about intended usage which is not provided by the questioner.

Comment: I think ensuring expansion-protection of fragile commands provided in `\myfun`'s argument in case of using `\edef` is up to the user. Such commands are processed when the work of `\myfun` is done.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I think that's intended. wipet's "philosophy" (also with OpTeX) seems to be "make the implementation as simple as possible" (possibly at the cost of "correctness" in some cases)

Comment: @user202729 I corrected my bug in `\myfun`, so now it is working with `\myfun{a}` too. "Correctness" in some cases like curly braces is problematic. What user mean when he write e.g. `\myfun{{a\\b}}`? If user needs a more funcionality then it can be done by `\unexpanded`, `\scatextokens` etc. primitives. And if you don't want to leave `\fi` when expansion hits first unexpandable token, then you can use `\afterfi` macro. But this was not given in your task.

Comment: @user202729 I like the philosophy of wipet: 1) The code is focused on what is really needed in practice and unneeded complexity is avoided. This is an aspect of efficiency. Sometimes I tend to be carried away and then I produce code which probably also handles a range of edge cases correctly and which can be handled/maintained by experts but cannot be handled by a novice to whom it is passed on in the form of the answer to a question. 2) The code is kept understandable for novices so that they can learn. When they have learned they can implement more obscure things themselves if really needed.

Answer (score 2):

You specified

- neither the desired behavior in case space before `\\` is omitted,
- nor the desired behavior in edge cases like the argument of `\myfun` being empty/blank,
- nor whether the focus is on the result of typesetting (probably in mathmode) or on obtaining a set of tokens (e.g., for further processing)—for the sake of having my fun I assumed the latter,
- nor whether expandability/robustness is of interest. For the sake of having my fun I assumed expandability is of interest.

The following macro-mechanism `\myfun` might work out as long as

- its argument does not contain the sequence `\ForBidden /` (unless nested in curly braces) and
- the token `\ForBidden` is not defined to be `\outer`.

Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the mechanism's result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps on `\myfun`.
The mechanism does without any `\if..\else..\fi`-thingies, thus can handle arguments containing unbalanced `\if..` or `\else` or `\fi`.
I ensured arguments being nested in curly braces while the expansion-cascade forming the mechanism is running —things being nested in curly braces ensures that `\\` contained in `\myfun`'s argument won't disturb the gathering of a table/alignment during the expansion-cascade and that within tables/alignments you can use the mechanism for extracting things that contain `&` and the like.
The mechanism is based on expansion only and therefore the mechanism itself should work out in pure-expansion-contexts as well (e.g., within `\csname..\endcsname`, inside `\edef`, inside `\expanded`, during `\romannumeral`-expansion/while expanding tokens for finding components of TeX-⟨number⟩-quantities or the left brace of a ⟨general text⟩, ...).
I tried my very best at ensuring that no undesired removal of curly braces takes place.

In case you use this mechanism within `\edef` or the like, ensuring protection/prevention of expansion of fragile commands provided with the argument of `\myfun` is up to you. Tokens coming from the argument of `\myfun` are processed when the process of performing the expansion-cascade initiated by `\myfun` has terminated, i.e., tokens coming from the argument of `\myfun` are processed when `\myfun`'s work is done. (In LaTeX in many situations you can do this by prepending `\protect` or by defining macros as robust commands, e.g.,in terms of `\protected` or via `\DeclareRobustCommand` or the like. Commands defined via `\NewDocumentCommand` are robust, too.)

`\myfun` processes an argument holding a `\\`-separated list as follows:
The set of tokens forming the first element is extracted.
Leading and trailing explicit space tokens are removed from that set of tokens if present.
Then one level of curly braces surrounding the entire remaining set of tokens is stripped off if present. This way you can use one level of surrounding curly braces for hiding leading/trailing explicit space tokens that shall not get removed.

I give no warranties. Usage is at your own risk.

```tex
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00
%%.............................................................................
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\CheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\stopromannumeral\secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\stopromannumeral\firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\trimtrailspaces#1{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\trimtrailspacesloop{{}}#1\ForBidden/ \ForBidden/\ForBidden/ {{}#1}%
  }\stopromannumeral
}%
\long\def\trimtrailspacesloop#1 \ForBidden/#2\ForBidden/ #3{%
  \CheckWhetherNull{#2}{% no trailing space
    \firstoftwo\stopromannumeral#3%
  }{% trailing space
    \trimtrailspacesloop#1\ForBidden/ \ForBidden/\ForBidden/ {#1}%
  }%
}%
\firstoftwo{\def\gobblespace}{} {}%
\long\def\trimleadspaces#1{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\trimleadspacesloop\ForBidden/#1\ForBidden/ \ForBidden/\ForBidden/{#1}%
  }\stopromannumeral
}%
\long\def\trimleadspacesloop#1\ForBidden/ #2\ForBidden/\ForBidden/#3{%
  \CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% Leading space
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\gobblespace#3}}%
    {\trimleadspacesloop\ForBidden/#2\ForBidden/\ForBidden/}%
  }{% no leading space
    \stopromannumeral#3%
  }%
}%
\long\def\extractfirstdoubleslashed#1{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\extractdoubleslashedB{{}}#1\\\ForBidden/%
  }\stopromannumeral
}%
\long\def\extractdoubleslashedB#1\\#2\ForBidden/{%
  \firstoftwo\stopromannumeral#1%
}%
\long\def\removebraces#1{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\firstoftwo#1{}{}}{\stopromannumeral#1}{%
      \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\firstoftwo{}#1}{\expandafter\stopromannumeral\secondoftwo{}#1}{%
        \stopromannumeral#1%
      }%
    }%
  }\stopromannumeral
}%
\long\def\myfun#1{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
  \expandafter\removebraces\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
    \expandafter\trimtrailspaces\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
      \expandafter\trimleadspaces\expandafter{%
         \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
         \extractfirstdoubleslashed{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testA
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{a}%
}%
\show\testA

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testB
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{a \\ b}%
}%
\show\testB

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testC
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ a \\ b}%
}%
\show\testC

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testD
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ a\\ b}%
}%
\show\testD

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testE
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{a \\ b \\ c}%
}%
\show\testE

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testF
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{$\theta$ \\ b \\ c}%
}%
\show\testF

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testG
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ \fi unbalanced \\ b \\ c}%
}%
\show\testG

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testH
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{}%
}%
\show\testH

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testI
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ }%
}%
\show\testI

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testJ
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ \\ }%
}%
\show\testJ

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testK
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{\\}%
}%
\show\testK

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testL
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \myfun{ { $\theta$ } \\ b \\ c}%
}%
\show\testL

\bye
```

The example produces the following messages on terminal:

```
> \testA=macro:
->a.
l.122 \show\testA
                 
? 
> \testB=macro:
->a.
l.129 \show\testB
                 
? 
> \testC=macro:
->a.
l.136 \show\testC
                 
? 
> \testD=macro:
->a.
l.143 \show\testD
                 
? 
> \testE=macro:
->a.
l.150 \show\testE
                 
? 
> \testF=macro:
->$\theta $.
l.157 \show\testF
                 
? 
> \testG=macro:
->\fi unbalanced.
l.164 \show\testG
                 
? 
> \testH=macro:
->.
l.171 \show\testH
                 
? 
> \testI=macro:
->.
l.178 \show\testI
                 
? 
> \testJ=macro:
->.
l.185 \show\testJ
                 
? 
> \testK=macro:
->.
l.192 \show\testK
                 
? 
> \testL=macro:
-> $\theta $ .
l.199 \show\testL
```